# Connect MySql database to MVC Project

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, mysql-connector, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to connect my MVC web application to a MySQL database. I've downloaded and installed the ADO.NET connector driver for MySQL and inserted the following lines into Web.config:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>      
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnection" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Data source=server_address;Database=database_name;user id=username;password=password;" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

And I've added these MySQL references:

[image: Project References]

But when I try to add an ADO.NET Model from the database I don't have a select option for the MySQL Database:

[image]

What am I missing? From everything I have researched I should have all of the necessary parts. Thank in advance.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6**

Check out that post

Comment: Still not working. I have tried uninstalling the connectors and VS plugin and reinstalling, but still nothing. Not sure what's going on.